# String compression using Python in order to compress the size to a fixed length

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, encoding, compression, hashcode

We have table say "analysis_data_table" from where I am fetching a column named "tags" where the entries in this column can vary from an empty record to a long string containing either sql queries, http urls etc.

My purpose is to compress this field before storing it and decompress when I need.

**Note:
this compressed string still needs to have the storable entries as I have to save this back in some database table column only.**

the compressed string maybe a meaningless series of hafazard strings(preferably fixed length) which can be reconverted into the original string.

e.g.

```
'''
input_string = "Python is language"

output_string = some_encoding(input_string)

which gives maybe "r%234khsjlfgkjlslll;dl;hghfd76890sjkjl7897" (larger than the i/p string)

also if

input_string = "Prerequisiste to learn data science is having command over atleast one programming language"

output_string = some_encoding(input_string)

which gives maybe "m$264khsjlfgkjlslll;dl;hghfd76890snmjl7895" (larger than the i/p string)
'''
```

so we can note the size is same and storable in both the encodings

Kindly assist in an encoding way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you mean "compress" or "encode"? It's not much of a compression if your string gets larger with it. You also should really include what is your purpose with all of this -- that definitely helps understanding your requirement a lot better.

Comment: compression is the major task, to be honest. The purpose is like: I want to extract the long string say combination of a long URL and a SQL query and then compress it to a small string and then make a dictionary key out of it. Basically next time I will have to find a similar key somewhere else in the database and I will increase the count to this key. But in order to be more readable I want this key to be small.

Comment: So, you're actually talking about hashing?

Comment: I thought about hashing but then can we decode it , I found we cannot retrieve the old message back after hashing.

Comment: From the title of your question, compressing (losslessly) to a _fixed size_ is not possible. There will always exist inputs that are not only not compressible, but that will in fact slightly expand.

Answer (score 0):

There are many lossless compression algorithms. One option is using the [`zlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) library:

```py
import zlib

input_string = "Python is language"
compressed = zlib.compress(bytes(input_string, 'utf-8'))
print(compressed)
```

gives `b'x\x9c\x0b\xa8,\xc9\xc8\xcfS\xc8,V\xc8I\xccK/MLO\x05\x00A$\x06\xe3'`.

This is binary data (26 bytes) which generally should be shorter than the input strings but that depends on how the strings are encoded. You would have to store it differently in your database, e.g. creating a new binary type column. Because of overhead to the compression, larger inputs will yield a better compression rate. There's no way to create a fixed length output, except if you used a hash function which is not reversible (i.e. you cannot recover the original input).

To recover the original data from the compression, use:

```py
original = zlib.decompress(compressed).decode('utf-8')
print(original)
```

yielding `'Python is language'`.

Comment: Thanks, Jan. Actually I already tried zlib, but the output seems to be not savable in the format of key.
The purpose is like: I want to extract the long string say combination of a long URL and a SQL query and then compress it to a small string and then make a dictionary key out of it. Basically next time I will have to find a similar key somewhere else in the database and I will increase the count to this key. But in order to be more readable I want this key to be small.

Comment: If you don't mind another lookup, you can move the strings to a separate table and add a foreign key reference to the original table.

Comment: I know but then anyways connection to database and that other table becomes a dependency right ? that is why I was thinking on some coding way outs.

Comment: If you extract your data to somewhere else then that will always be a dependency. It's better to keep it together in the same database rather than, say, an external file or something like that.

Comment: ok yes that can be done actually, thanks.